# NumPy broadcasting doesn't work

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I am trying to broadcast the difference between two vectors. This works for a simple case like this:

```py
In[1] : data = np.array([1,2])
In[2] : centers = np.array([[2,2],[3,3]])

In[3] : data - center

Out[3] : array([[-1,  0],
               [-2, -1]])
```

But when I try to do the same thing but with larger dimension this won't work

```py
In [4]: data = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[6,7]])
In [5]: data
Out [5]: array([[1,2],
                [3,4],
                [6,7]])

In [6]: centers = np.array([[2,2],[3,3]])
In [7]: centers
Out [7]: array([[2,2],
                [3,3]])
```

And I want to perform `data - centers` so I can get as output:

```py
array([[[-1,0],
        [-2,-1]],
       [[1,2],
        [0,1]],
       [[4,5],
        [3,4]]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case you need to insert an extra axis into `data`:

```
>>> data[:, None] - centers
array([[[-1,  0],
        [-2, -1]],

       [[ 1,  2],
        [ 0,  1]],

       [[ 4,  5],
        [ 3,  4]]])
```

Originally `data.shape` is `(3, 2)` and `centers.shape` is `(2, 2)`. NumPy isn't able to broadcast arrays with these shapes together because the lengths of the first axes are not compatible (they need to be the same length, or one of them needs to be `1`).

Inserting the extra dimension, `data[:, None]` has shape `(3, 1, 2)` and then the lengths of the axes align correctly:

```
(3, 1, 2) 
   (2, 2) 
    #  #
    #  # lengths are equal for this axis
    #
    # 1 is compatible with any length
```